# Dual Booting, Windows10-Ubuntu 18.04.4LTS, From USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I am trying to run Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS from a USB stick. My OS is W10 Pro. I've tried creating the USB with Rufus, LinuxLive USB Creator, and Universal USB Installer.

I've been getting a lot of different errors while trying to do this and (as far as I know) I've tested all the solutions I've found on this forum and on other sites.

The error message I'm dealing with right now is the following:
SYSLINUX: No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found
And a prompt that reads "boot:"

I manage to get a different error message some times, which reads:

Failed to load ldlinux.c32
Boot failed: please change disks and press a key to continue

I've tried burning the Ubuntu ISO (downloaded multiple times both as direct download and as torrent) using 3 different ISO to USB apps. Those are Rufus, LinuxLive USB Creator, and Universal USB Installer.

I've tried formatting the USB as FAT32 and as exFAT (this last one gives me a different error, which reads something like this: "exF unplug USB and press any key to restart".

And finally I also tried renaming the following:
isolinux –> syslinux (folder)
isolinux.bin –> syslinux.bin
isolinux.cfg –> syslinux.cfg
Something I do have to say about renaming is that as soon as I renamed the folder, it would get wiped out. So I just created a new syslinux folder and pasted all files from isolinux folder there. Then I deleted the isolinux folder

Anyone knows what else I can try?

Comment: How did you create your usb stick? Using which operating system? Which Ubuntu did you try to install?  Your description starts in the middle of the problem, not at the beginning

Comment: Added first paragraph answering your questions

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Unless you are using the USB to install Ubuntu it might be best to make a Full install to USB, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227845/running-live-usb-on-2-different-pcs/1227847#1227847 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step