# Is it 'safe' and easy to update Ubuntu running on a USB?

Tags: usb, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on a USB drive, and would like to update it to the latest version (also hoping this will solve the occasional freezing issues). I'm not very knowledgeable about how this running on a USB drive exactly works (someone else made it for me), so I wanted to get a confirmation about whether simply going through the normal update process would work (as if Ubuntu is installed on my laptop). With 'the normal update process' I mean downloading the update, maybe restarting if required, etc. Restarting for example wouldn't really work as usual I think, as I always have to manually boot Ubuntu up again.

Comment: It is not clear if you have a persistent live USB or full install in an USB. The answer will depend on that. See [What would be the differences between a persistent USB live session and a instal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal)

Comment: A live install should have an 'install ubuntu' icon on it when booted up, a full install will not have the install icon.  Updates will be safe and easy, but will not remain with a live USB after reboot, only with a full install.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen 'install ubuntu' on start up, and each time I start up ubuntu again it's the same as where I left it (as it would be when installed on a laptop/desktop). I assume I have the full install then?

Comment: In another post I've also soon that for an installed version you should see '<user>@<hostname>:~$' in the terminal, which is the case for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Ubuntu USB

An Ubuntu persistent USB saves all changes in a persistent file or partition, named "writable" or "casper-rw" and optional "home-rw".

Persistent files on FAT32 partitions are limited to 4GB, persistent partitions are limited only by disk size.

A full persistence file or partition will prevent a persistent USB from booting. An update or two will fill a 4GB file.

A full install stores data on an ext partition that does not limit size, a /home partition is optional.

Differences between Persistent installs and Full installs are shown here:

[Running live usb on 2 different PC's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227845/running-live-usb-on-2-different-pcs/1227847#1227847)

A Full install to USB is not much different than an install to Desktop or Laptop, updating is fine.

To confirm a Full install, look in the folder filesystem/cdrom, this is the root folder for a Live or Persistent drive. If there is nothing there, you have a Full install.